# Word for an idea or concept that cannot be summarised?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I came across an adjective describing ideas or notions (particularly relevant to a body of work such as literature or a philosophical system) that is unable to be summarised without losing the purpose or quality of the point. However, I cannot remember it.

It is not ineffable, nor atopy, because it already equates to a body of written work. Can anyone think of the appropriate word?

Comment: [Intricate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intricate) maybe?

Comment: Watch out for the [Berry paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox).

Comment: Why watch for the berry paradox?

Answer (score 5):

Consider *irreducible*.

> **Irreducible**
>   *adjective*
>   Not able to be reduced or simplified.
>   ‘literature is often irreducible to normative ideas’
>   [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/irreducible)

Answer (score 0):

"Unsummarisable" is probably the most obvious! (Or "unsummarizable" in American English)

Or:

"Unsimplifiable" - not capable of being simplified.

"Complex" - Consisting of many different and connected parts. Although some people use this as a synonym for "complicated" it does not simply mean "difficult".

Answer (score -1):

**inexplicable**, adj. (and adv.) and n.  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/95121?redirectedFrom=inexplicable#eid)

> 3. That cannot be explained; inscrutabl

e, unintelligible; (in recent use) that cannot be accounted for, unaccountable.